# Easiest way to set up a file based database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm developing an application, in part to learn new technologies - in this instance Entity Framework.
I'm using .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2013. I need some way to store data that doesn't involve running an SQL server on my tired old laptop (not even the lightweight one) and works with Entity Framework. Ideally I would like something that just stores data in a file. I have a few basic requirements:

- A simple relational database. Max 10 tables, this is a prototype, so
  the tables won't get very big
- Ability to design the database in some
  sort of GUI tool
- Ability to generate Entity Framework database model
  from the DB. I don't want to type those in manually.
- No proprietary software other than what I'm already using - i.e. I don't own a MS Access license
- Something that ACTUALLY
  WORKS

I've spent the better part of today trying to get VS2013 to connect me to an SQLite database that I've created. I never got anywhere. SQLite is simply not listed among the available types of data sources. I've read StackOverflow posts about this issue, I'm done trying to make it work. (this is where the frustration you can sense in this post stems from - this is SO not the point of the exercise, yet I've wasted so much time with it)
Is there any other file based database technology I could use?

Answer (score 2):

Your needs are not compatible, the best choice is SQLite but you can not generate model from database and must use EF as CodeFirst .

and your problem with SQLite can easily fixed by using correct provider and configuration : http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html

Comment: SQLite does not support Code First migrations

Comment: For this i say "Your needs are not compatible" ;)
You can't find a lightweight file based database that meet your needs. also see EF 7 , it has good support of SQLite as local database engine.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use SQL Server Compact in combination with my free SQL Server Compact Toolbox VS extension:

> A simple relational database. Max 10 tables, this is a prototype, so the tables won't get very big

- SQL CE supports all standard relational paradigms, and has a max database size of 4 GB

> Ability to design the database in some sort of GUI tool

- The extension allows you to do this in Visual Studio

> Ability to generate Entity Framework database model from the DB. I don't want to type those in manually.

- Yes, fully supported

> No proprietary software other than what I'm already using - i.e. I don't own a MS Access license

- SQL Compact is free and freely distributable

Comment: PS: I am the author of the Toolbox extension